# Retrieving one property from jquery .data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have created object:

```
element.data('itemAtrr', { idItem: iditem[i], itemName: names[i], divType: types[i] } );
```

When i do:

```
console.log(element.data("itemAtrr"));
```

Everything works  absolutely fine.

But when i try to retrieve one property like:

```
console.log(element.data("itemAtrr.itemName"));
```

or

```
console.log(element.data("itemAtrr[itemName]"));
```

it returns "UNDEFINED". What am i doing wrong? Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the key to search for elementa on `data` store, there is no element with key `itemAtrr.itemName` or `itemAtrr[itemName]`. Use this instead to access object property

```
console.log(element.data("itemAtrr").itemName);
```

Notice that you first get the object using the key provided at save time. Then you access properties as you would do with any JS object. You can't do it in a single step.

Comment: Here's the documention for [`$element.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

Answer (score 1):

First retrieve the object, then dial down into it:

`console.log(element.data("itemAtrr").itemName);`